# Create a function which will return 4 output columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Create table holiday master which will have column name as holiday date,day (Sunday,monday or any public holiday holiday).

Create a function which will return 4 output columns: Date, Day of month, year & day.
Date will be working dates between 2 dates (Ignore dates present in holiday master table)

```
CREATE function DATENEWww
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @MIDDLEDATE DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2013/05/01'
SET @EndDate = '2013/05/10'

SELECT getday()'Day', getDATE() 'Today', YEAR(GETDATE()) 'YEAR Part'
SELECT 
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME (DW, @MIDDLEDATE)='SELECT HOLIDAY_DATE FROM HOLIDAY_MASTER' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

  END
```

Comment: i have tried this using some code but could not get result

Comment: Tag dbms used, since most of them are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to PSM (aka stored procedures.)

Comment: How come you expect us to do your work/school work. (Either you get paid for our work, or you don't learn anything...)

Comment: nop its not the case...i have tried code..its does not work some how

Comment: Post the code you tried, sample data, desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Table function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CalculateNumberOFWorkDays] (@StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime)
RETURNS RETURNS @Results TABLE (
    [Date]         datetime,
    [DayOfMonth]   int,
    [Year]         int,
    [Day]          int
)
AS BEGIN

SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @StartDate), 0) 
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @EndDate), 0) 

DECLARE @WORKDAYS INT
SELECT @WORKDAYS = (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
           -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
           -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
           -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)


INSERT @Results ([Date], [DayOfMonth], [Year], [Day])
SELECT <your query here>

RETURN 
END
```

Comment: see i do not have sample data. all i need to do is display four columns day, date,year and no.of days between any two dates.

Comment: you can consider any two dates

Comment: Do you date calculations and insert them as columns in the @Results table. Then query the columns using: select * from dbo.CalculateNumberOfWorkDays(@StartDate, @EndDate)